# Align a box to the right of a container fluid Bootstrap 3

Tags: html, bootstrap-4

I'm still struggling with Bootstrap and I've just started a web application using Bootstrap 3. I would like to align a box on the right side of the screen but I can't find my solution after a few hours of research and testing... Here is where I would like to place it:

[image: example]

Here is the existing code:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row mt-4 mb-4">
        <div class="col-md-12 mt-4 mb-4">
            @if($user->object->bio)
                <blockquote>{{ $user->object->bio }}</blockquote>
            @endif
            @if($albums->count())
                @include('pages.partials.album-stream-2021', ['albums' => $albums])
            @else
                @include('partials.no-results', ['message'=>'This user have no albums uploaded'])
            @endif
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open this example full screen:) you should be good to go:)

```css
div {
   border:1px solid;
   }
```

```html
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
<!-- Optional theme -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-rHyoN1iRsVXV4nD0JutlnGaslCJuC7uwjduW9SVrLvRYooPp2bWYgmgJQIXwl/Sp" crossorigin="anonymous">
<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div class="container-fluid">
   <div id="DivLeft" class="col-md-3">
      left Side bar
   </div>
   <div id="DivMain" class="col-md-6">
        <div id="card" class="col-md-4">
                  <div class="card-body">
                     <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
                     <p class="card-text">
                        Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the
                        card's content.
                     </p>
                     <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Button</button>
                  </div>
        </div>
         <div id="card" class="col-md-4">
                  <div class="card-body">
                     <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
                     <p class="card-text">
                        Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the
                        card's content.
                     </p>
                     <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Button</button>
               </div>
            </div>
         <div id="card" class="col-md-4">
                  <div class="card-body">
                     <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
                     <p class="card-text">
                        Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the
                        card's content.
                     </p>
                     <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Button</button>
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
      
      <div id="DivRight" class="col-md-3 ">
         right Side bar 
      </div>
</div>
```